# MySQL LEFT JOIN Multiple Conditions

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables: A and B linked by "group_id". 
2 variables I'm using: `$keyword, $_SESSION['user_id']`

**A**
group_id
keyword

**B**
id
group_id
user_id

I want to be able to select all the groups that this user is not in based on a keyword search.

Therefore the goal is to SELECT all the rows in A WHERE the user_id!={$_SESSION['user_id'} for the corresponding group_id in B AND like the keyword.

this is what I tried:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON a.group_id=b.group_id 
WHERE a.keyword LIKE '%".$keyword."%' 
AND b.user_id!=$_SESSION{['user_id']} 
GROUP BY group_id
```

However, it does not find any rows (matches) unless I remove `AND b.user_id!=$_SESSION{['user_id']}` in which case it will also include groups the user is already in - which is not what I want.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statements

Answer (score 52):

Just move the extra condition into the JOIN ON criteria, this way the existence of b is not required to return a result

```
SELECT a.* FROM a 
    LEFT JOIN b ON a.group_id=b.group_id AND b.user_id!=$_SESSION{['user_id']} 
    WHERE a.keyword LIKE '%".$keyword."%' 
    GROUP BY group_id
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, however, this did not work. It simply returns all the rows in Table 'a' including the ones where the b.user_id equals the $_SESSION['user_id'].  I'm not sure why but I assume it has to do with the fact that its a left join?

Comment: I think you're close enough to know the answer :) Try using an INNER JOIN instead of a left join

Comment: No INNER JOIN does not work.  If I use INNER JOIN then it will only pull the rows from Table A that have a corresponding group_id in table B.  I need it to all pull the rows in Table A except the ones where the user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] (for that particular group_id) in B.

Comment: i did not know you can add "AND" in LEFT JOIN "ON" haha.. silly me. thanks

Answer (score 21):

Correct answer is simply:

```
SELECT a.group_id
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON a.group_id=b.group_id  and b.user_id = 4
where b.user_id is null
  and a.keyword like '%keyword%'
```

Here we are checking `user_id = 4` (your user id from the session). Since we have it in the join criteria, it will return null values for any row in table b that does not match the criteria - ie, any group that that user_id is NOT in.

From there, all we need to do is filter for the null values, and we have all the groups that your user is not in.

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0aa96/1)

Answer (score 1):

Above answers are correct. Another way to achieve this is;

```
SELECT a.group_id
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON (a.group_id, b.user_id) = (b.group_id, 4)
where b.user_id is null
  and a.keyword like '%keyword%'
```

[Complete Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0aa96/452/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.group_id IN 
(SELECT group_id FROM b WHERE b.user_id!=$_SESSION{'[user_id']} AND b.group_id = a.group_id)
WHERE a.keyword LIKE '%".$keyword."%';
```