# Select row from left join table where multiple conditions are true

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I currently have the following situation:

I am trying to build a filter with which I can select every row that has a set of given properties. I will explain this with an example:

```
SELECT table1.name FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
WHERE table2.propertyID = "First PropertyID" AND table2.propertyID = "Second PropertyID"
```

Obviously, this returns null every time. But I can not figure out how to do this..

Table 1 has two columns: ID and Name.
Table 2 looks like this:

```
| ID  | PropertyID |
|  1  |     3      |
|  1  |     5      |
|  1  |     7      |
|  2  |     6      |
|  2  |     1      |
```

I would like to be able to select the rows from Table 1 which are connected to e.g. PropertyID 3 and 5.

I have found a lot of examples, but these all use OR or IN, but I need AND is this situation.

Is this even possible with MySQL or do I need to create some workaround?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit 1:**

Table 1 looks like this:

```
| ID  |   Name    |
|  1  |   test    |
|  2  |   hello   |
```

In my case, I need to do more LEFT JOINS to reach the table2, but I thought this example would be sufficient to get the correct method.

Comment: Can you post some info from table1 and then your expected results so we can try to recreate it? Do you mean to say that only table1 ID 1 should be returned because it is related to both 3 and 5?

Comment: So, if do a left join all rows from table 1 will be returned, right? I think you really want an inner join here, unless I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: Did you mean `table2.propertyID` instead `table2.property`?

Comment: @RubahMalam Yes, that's correct, I will update my post.

Comment: OP, I was able to get this to work in SQL Fiddle. Does it not work to solve your whole problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you take one step back and consider this problem without the join. You want to know which rows are related to both properties 3 and 5. You can do that without the join like this:

```
SELECT tab1ID
FROM table2
WHERE propertyID = 3 OR propertyID = 5
GROUP BY tab1ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

To get the information from table 1, you can do an inner join so that only id 1 will be returned:

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.tab1ID = t1.id
WHERE t2.propertyid = 3 OR t2.propertyid = 5
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a736/5) example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will look into this within a couple of hours

Comment: I am using your second answer, and it seems to work when there are two WHERE clauses. However, if I just want to select `t2.propertyid = 3`, I get zero results returned. Do you know why this is the case?

Comment: Excuse me, that was a stupid question! I need to make the COUNT(*) = int variabele in my java code. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Do you know why this is not working with '!=' or '<>'?

Comment: @bashoogzaad TL;DR try using 'AND' instead of 'OR' when you are negating the condition. I am about to go to class but I will try to edit my question at some point with an explanation.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but I already have the answer. You should check it out, it is really great: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407753/select-not-working-when-using-in-where-clause-using-group-by-and-having-coun

Comment: @bashoogzaad Glad you got it! Yes, juergen is really good at answering MySQL questions. :)

Answer (score 3):

When outer join, move outer table conditions to the ON clause, else outer join behaves just like an inner join:

```
SELECT table1.name FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
    AND   table2.propertyID = "First PropertyID"
    AND   table2.property = "Second PropertyID"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried your solution, but now the query just returns everything, it seems to ignore the AND after the ON.

Comment: @bashoogzaad, do you mean you get more rows returned when you add the table2 conditions to the ON clause - with AND?!? Do SELECT * and see if the result makes any sense!

Comment: I just get every single row when executing the query above, while I only want the rows in which the AND of the LEFT JOIN is true. Screenshot here: http://oi62.tinypic.com/1zpl2t4.jpg. As you can see, it returns 1209 rows, while it should only return 20 or something like that.

Comment: But all rows seem to be correct according to the conditions? Maybe your example was a bit too simplified?

Comment: No, it just returns every row, not taking the conditions into account. Maybe it has something to do with this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637929/mysql-left-join-multiple-conditions . See comments of first answer.

Comment: I don't understand how this works. The condition `AND table2.propertyid = 'first' AND table2.propertyid = 'second'` will never be true, so it's just going to select all rows from table1.

Comment: @McAdam331, it says table2.**propertyID** = "First PropertyID"
    AND   table2.**property** = "Second PropertyID"

Comment: Well I assumed that was a typo, there's no `property` column in OP's question.

Comment: @McAdam331, you may be right, this is all very confusing. I need either another cuf of coffee, or rather a beer by now.

Comment: I agree with @McAdam331, this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this:
use `OR` instead `AND`

```
SELECT table1.name FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
WHERE table2.propertyID = "First PropertyID" 
OR table2.propertyID = "Second PropertyID"
```

Or use`IN`

```
SELECT table1.name FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
WHERE table2.propertyID IN( "First PropertyID","Second PropertyID")
```

but i guess, you need `Group By` funtion too.