# SELECT not working when using != in WHERE clause (using GROUP BY and HAVING COUNT)

Tags: mysql, sql

This question is based on: [Select row from left join table where multiple conditions are true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28368305/select-row-from-left-join-table-where-multiple-conditions-are-true)

I am now trying to select rows from Table 1, which do not have a connection in Table 2 to a certain property ID.

These are the tables:

**Table 1**

```
| ID  |   Name    |
|  1  |   test    |
|  2  |   hello   |
```

**Table 2**

```
| ID  | PropertyID |
|  1  |     3      |
|  1  |     6      |
|  1  |     7      |
|  2  |     6      |
|  2  |     1      |
```

I am using the following query (which is working with '='):

```
SELECT tab1ID
FROM table2
WHERE propertyID != 3 OR propertyID = 6
GROUP BY tab1ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

This query should return ID=2, but it returns zero rows. What I am doing wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** I had given a MWE but this is my actual query:

```
SELECT transactionline.total FROM transactionline
LEFT JOIN product_variant ON product_variant.SKU = transactionline.SKU 
LEFT JOIN product ON product_variant.productID = product.productID 
LEFT JOIN connect_option_product ON connect_option_product.productID = product.productID 
LEFT JOIN productattribute_option ON productattribute_option.optionID = connect_option_product.optionID 
WHERE productattribute_option.optionID = 4 OR productattribute_option.optionID = 9
GROUP BY transactionline.lineID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 
AND SUM(productattribute_option.optionID = 4) = 0
AND SUM(productattribute_option.optionID = 9) > 0
```

A product can have multiple connections to the optionID's. The goal of this query is to select the total amount where some filters are true or false.

Comment: It should return 2, not 1, right?

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that, my bad!

Comment: It should retirm also ID = 1 or am I missing something here? Anyway in [SQLFiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e722/2) it works for me

Comment: Why "propertyID != 3 OR propertyID = 6"? 6 is always already != 3, i.e. skip that = 6 condition if you only want != 3.

Comment: @jarlh see my updated post. A product can have multiple connections to optionID's, so I want to do a WHERE on the same column (as described in the linked question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your grouping is correct. But you need to count how many times the value you **do not** want is in your group. That count must be zero.

```
SELECT tab1ID
FROM table2
GROUP BY tab1ID
HAVING sum(propertyID = 6) > 0
AND sum(propertyID = 3) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am trying to make this work with my actual query (see updated post), but haven't figured it out yet. Are there any things to consider when you see the the actual query?

Comment: I forgot the remove the `where` clause. Updated it. Why do you need a `having count(*) = 1`?

Comment: Thank you very much, this is working perfectly! This is also working for 'EQUAL', so it replaces my old query! (which was using HAVING COUNT).